# How can i fix the denied: Not Authorized message when i push a docker image to AWS ECR?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, docker-image, amazon-ecr

I am trying to upload a docker image to AWS ECR using the push commands that Amazon indicates but I always get the same message:
denied: Not Authorized

I gave my IAM user the following permissions:

AmazonEC2 ContainerRegistry Full Access

AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryPowerUser

AmazonECS_FullAccess

AmazonElasticContainerRegistryPublicPowerUser

I also tried to follow this instructions :
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/docker-push-ecr-image.html

but i get a diferent error : no basic auth credentials

Comment: Are you currently signed in to the correct aws account?

Comment: yes, i use sudo aws configure and copy pasted the access key of my IAM user and the secret access key

Comment: But you still have to `aws login`, don't you?

Answer (score 0):

You either need to install the [AWS ECR Credentials Helper for Docker](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-ecr-credential-helper), or get the `aws ecr get-login-password` command working.

If you are getting the message "no basic auth credentials" then you haven't configured your current command shell to use any AWS credentials yet. There are [multiple ways](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-configure.html) to configure the AWS CLI with your AWS credentials, but I recommend using the Environment Variables approach as it will also be picked up automatically by the ECR Credentials Helper.